# IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/dev/null'

Tags: google-cloud-sdk, ioerror, raiserror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5acl9.png)

getting this error for python2.7.18, Google cloud SDK version 412.0.0.0 and app-engine-python: 1.9.101

running localhost:8080

Comment: I've Ubuntu system v22.04

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.